# Resetting select options based on choice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following data set

```
array:4 [
  "data" => array:2 [
    2015 => array:2 [
      "english" => array:1 [
        "chips" => array:1 [
          0 => "img1.png"
        ]
      ]
      "french" => array:1 [
        "mussles" => array:1 [
          0 => "img1.png"
        ]
      ]
    ]
    2016 => array:2 [
      "indian" => array:1 [
        "madras" => array:1 [
          0 => "img1.png"
        ]
      ]
      "italien" => array:1 [
        "pasta" => array:1 [
          0 => "img1.png"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

To appropriately display the correct data I do the following

```
<select id="year" class="form-control">
    @foreach($fileData["data"] as $year => $countries)
        <option value="{{ $year }}">{{ $year }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<select id="country" class="form-control hide">
    @foreach($fileData["data"] as $year => $countries)
        @foreach ($countries as $country => $dishes)
            <option class="year-{{ $year }} hide" value="{{ $country }}">{{ $country }}</option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>

<select id="dish" class="form-control hide">
    @foreach($fileData["data"] as $year => $countries)
        @foreach ($countries as $country => $dishes)
            @foreach ($dishes as $dish => $images)
                <option class="year-{{ $year }} country-{{ $country }} hide" value="{{ $dish }}">{{ $dish }}</option>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</select>
```

So the second and third select are hidden until the previous one is chosen.
Within JavaScript I do

```
var getSelectedYear = function() {
    return $("#year option:selected").val();
}

var getSelectedCountry = function() {
    return $("#country option:selected").val();
}

$('#year').change(function() {
    $("#country option.year-" + getSelectedYear()).removeClass('hide');
    $("#country").removeClass('hide');
})

$('#country').change(function() {
    $("#dish option.year-" + getSelectedYear() + ".country-" + getSelectedCountry()).removeClass('hide');
    $("#dish").removeClass('hide');
})
```

So if I choose 2015 in the first select, the second select will display English and french.  If I then choose English, the third select will show chips.

This all works fine.  My problem is this.  If I choose 2015, English and chips, and then change English to french, the third select option now shows chips and mussles instead of just mussles.  So it works fine it done in order, but as soon as you change something I need to make the following select options reset before dynamically filling them up.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about hiding all of the other options before you unhide the one you want?

```
$('#year').change(function() {
    // hides all the options
    $("#county option").addClass("hide");
    $("#country option.year-" + getSelectedYear()).removeClass('hide');
    $("#country").removeClass('hide');

    // gets the value of the first available option and resets your dropdown to that
    var first_val = $("#country option:not('.hide')").first().val();
    $("#country").val(first_val);
    // manually trigger the change so that it propagates to the following dropdown
    $("#country").trigger("change");
})

$('#country').change(function() {
    // hides all the options
    $("#dish option").addClass("hide");
    $("#dish option.year-" + getSelectedYear() + ".country-" + getSelectedCountry()).removeClass('hide');
    $("#dish").removeClass('hide');

    // gets the value of the first available option and resets your dropdown to that
    var first_val = $("#dish option:not('.hide')").first().val();
    $("#dish").val(first_val);
})
```

This adds the "hide" class to all of the available options, then unhides only the specific ones you want to be available.  In addition, it selects the first available option so you aren't left with a stale dropdown.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  There is one thing which I cant figure out though.  Say you choose 2015 > English, the third option displays chips as it should do.  But then say you change it to 2016, the second option changes correctly, but the third option still has chips and only changes when the second option is selected again.  If the year is reselected, is it possible to clear the third option until the second one is selected again?  Thanks

Comment: Ah yeah. I was hoping that setting the value would trigger a `change` event automatically.  Since it doesn't, trigger it manually.  I'll add that to my answer